# export all the products with all fields as a csv file Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

We have 4000 inventory Items , I want to export all the products with all custom fields and System fields of all products as a csv file.
can somebody help will the script.

Comment: Searches allow you to export results to Excel. It might be faster to just build a saved search of all Items with all fields rather than learn how to write SuiteScript for this task. It might be tedious, but it's most definitely cheaper. If you absolutely have to write a script, you will need to combine the `nlobjRecord.getAllFields` API with the `nlapiCreateFile` API, which supports creation of a CSV in the File Cabinet. I suggest reading the NS Help pages for `nlobjRecord` and `nlapiCreateFile`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried with search results , Considering we have 4000 products.I ended up getting [TRUNCATED - LIMIT REACHED] error.

Comment: You may have to chunk it into smaller files. File creation has a size limit, though I don't recall the exact limit off the top of my head. You may just have to group your results and into say chunks of 200 and create a separate file for each group.